# how to simplify typescript code with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's the code i try to simplify:

```
type ThunkType = {
  dispatch: AppDispatch;
  extra: AxiosInstance;
}
export const getAction = createAsyncThunk<void, string, ThunkType>(...)
```

Maybe in a way like this:

```
type NewType<T> =.....
export const getAction = createAsyncThunk<NewType<string>>(...)
```

Comment: Does this depend on third-party frameworks like axios and redux? If so please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that only needs native TS values and types.